Why might I be getting an error 403 for a presigned url when the S3 bucket has open policy and signing lambda has sufficient permissions?
I have a project like so: Client -> Gateway API -> Lambda -> signed url; User takes signed url -> S3 Post.
I am able to generate and return the signed url but every time I try to make a request with either postman or fetch, I get Error 403.
Here's my client side code
async function uploadPic()
{
    #getting file from input...
    var fileName = file.name;

    #uploadEventPhoto takes Cognito idToken from url and requests presigned url, I know for a fact cognito    works as I was able to use it for another resource in the API
    let url = await uploadEventPhoto(idToken)

    "tried using formData and also file directly in body, does't seem to affect the 403 error"
    let formData = new FormData()
    formData.append("file", file)
   
    const requestOptions = {
        method: 'PUT',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': "multipart/form-data"
        },
        body: formData
    };
   
    let putURLResponse= await fetch(url, requestOptions)
}

Here's the URL signing Lambda
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    #this works fine just omitted func definition
    rand_id = generate_random_string(8)

    client = boto3.client('s3',aws_access_key_id='REDACTED',aws_secret_access_key='REDACTED')
    resp = client.generate_presigned_url("put_object",
        Params={
            "Bucket":"REDACTED",
            "Key":"REDACTED/REDACTED"
        },
        ExpiresIn=300
        )

    return {
        'statusCode': 200,
        'headers': {
            'Content-Type': 'image/png',
            'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
            'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'POST, PUT, GET, OPTIONS',
            'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'Content-Type, Access-Control-Allow-Headers, Authorization, X-Requested-With'
        },
        'body': json.dumps(resp)
    }

async function uploadEventPhoto(idToken)
{
    //function name is a misnomer, was originally trying to pass data to a lambda that would put it in S3, now all it does is use cognito auth to call a lambda that returns the presigned url
    const url = 'https://REDACTED.execute-api.us-west-1.amazonaws.com/dev/Photos';
    const requestOptions = {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'Authorization': `Bearer ${idToken}`
        },
    };

    let resp = await fetch(url, requestOptions)
    let data = await resp.json()
    return data
}

Here's the bucket policy as well
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "PublicReadGetObject",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::REDACTED/*"
        },
        {
            "Sid": "S3PolicyStmt-DO-NOT-MODIFY-1719269888596",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "Service": "logging.s3.amazonaws.com"
            },
            "Action": "s3:PutObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::REDACTED/*",
            "Condition": {
                "StringEquals": {
                    "aws:SourceAccount": "REDACTED"
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "Sid": "Statement1",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": [
                "s3:PutObjectAcl",
                "s3:PutObject"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::REDACTED/*",
                "arn:aws:s3:::REDACTED"
            ]
        }
    ]
}

Roles/Users:

I made sure the Lambda's role had perms for S3, initially just putObject but now * just to cover every base

Tried creating new role with the right perms still no change.

Made new user and gave S3 perms and used access keys in the client hoping the user's perms would transfer to url.

Tried without access keys in client constructor to test passing the lambdas perms, neither worked.


S3 Bucket:

Initially only had public read but now has public read/write, still doesn't fix 403

Cors allows all origins and methods

made sure roles had access to aws:arn:::BUCKET and BUCKET/*

tried giving roles KMS perms since I saw that in another post on here


Other:

Also tried presigned_put_url() to no avail, switched to presigned_url() and still doesn't work

Tested user and role permissions to put in my S3 bucket with the simulator, both should work

It seems like the user perms would be transferred since the request link includes the role's AWSAccessKeyID but access advisor says its key hasn't been accessed??

I'm sure I've tried more that I can't remember but I'm losing my mind




# is not how you define comments in JavaScript. 2) You should remove the content-type header and let your browser set the correct value. 3) Please [edit] your question to include the definition for uploadEventPhoto as it seems critical to your problem


@Phil My bad, wrote the comments after the fact in the stackoverflow editor and slipped up while switching between python and js. Will try removing content-type and added uploadEventPhoto code

Don’t stress the stack overflow flamers..

Expires in 300?
Can you extend the seconds the url is active?
